# Overlapping widgets

Tags: android, android-layout

I have multiple widgets on the same spot in my `layout`. 3 of them are `Buttons` and 1 `TextView`.

I want to have the `TextView` above the `Buttons`. I can change which `Button` comes on top by simply switching the order of those `Buttons` in the `layout`. However, the `TextView` will never get on top of the `Buttons`.

The only way I managed to get the `TextView` on top was by adding `elevation`, but since I am also targeting API's below 21 it doesn't work as I want it to. Any idea how I can fix my issue?

Comment: Use `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two `LinearLayout`s inside a `FrameLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text View" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```